# estoy teniendo error en el juego de ahorcados tengo q aplicar corte de control y me esta dando error

Tags: c, algoritmos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef char tString[50];

typedef struct{
    tString marcas;
    tString frutas;
}trAhorcado;

trAhorcado vrAhorcado;

FILE * vfAhorcado;

void inicializacion();
void principioCorte();
void procesoCorte();
void finCorte();
void finalizacion();

typedef char campoControl;
int opcion,i,j,k,longitud,espacios,puntos;
char letra;
int aciertos;
int intentos;
int ganar;
char frase[30];

int main() {
    inicializacion();
    procesoCorte();
    finalizacion();
    
    return 0;
}


void inicializacion(){
    vfAhorcado = fopen("JuegoAhorcado.dat", "rb");
    fread(&vrAhorcado, sizeof(trAhorcado), 1, vfAhorcado);
    campoControl= vrAhorcado.marcas,vrAhorcado.frutas;
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("JUEGO EL AHORCADOOO \n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

void procesoCorte(){
    while(!feof(vfAhorcado)){
        principioCorte();
        while(!feof(vfAhorcado) && vrAhorcado.marcas, vrAhorcado.frutas == campoControl){
            fread(&vrAhorcado, sizeof(trAhorcado), 1, vfAhorcado);
        }
        finCorte();
    }
}
```

- ´Me esta tirando error en las lineas de campocontrol y no estaria
  entendiendo ya la cambie varias veces  typedef char campoControl;
  ´43 14  C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\trabajon integrador\juegoahorcado2 (1).c   [Error] expected identifier or '(' before '=' token
  52  70  C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\trabajon integrador\juegoahorcado2 (1).c   [Error] expected expression before 'campoControl'
  52  70  C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\trabajon integrador\juegoahorcado2 (1).c   [Error] expected expression before 'campoControl'´

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esos son lo erroress
51  67  C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\trabajon integrador\juegoahorcado2 (1).c   [Warning] comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esos son lo erroress
51  67  C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\trabajon integrador\juegoahorcado2 (1).c   [Warning] comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

Comment: Debes tener algún error de tipeo, qué quieres lograr con `campoControl= vrAhorcado.marcas,vrAhorcado.frutas;`?

Comment: osea me estuve guiando con otro ejercicio por eso cree la varible campocontrol para almacenar ese espacion en memoria en esta linea se iguala en lo ultimo a campocontrol por eso me esta confundiendo while(!feof(vfAhorcado) && vrAhorcado.marcas, vrAhorcado.frutas == campoControl){ que puedo igualar en vez de campocontrol

Comment: que me recomendarias hacer en este caso para arreglar el error me esta costando mucho

Comment: No termino de entender, `campoControl` es un alias para `char`. Qué quieres hacer con eso? Guardar algo en una variable?